# How to assign ID to any asp:ListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a dropdown list and i want to assign each listitem with an id

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ATime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
<asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>8AM-2PM</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>9AM-5PM</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>6PM-12AM</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>3PM-9PM</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Why do you need it? And a `ListItem` has a `Text` and `Value` property, so you could use those: `<asp:ListItem Text="8AM-2PM" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>`

Answer (score 2):

**ListItem** doesn't have an **ID** property, since it is not deriving from control so it does not have **ID**.

If you want to search the ListItem value that was posted from ListItemCollection (Items property) then you can do like this-

```
Dim listItem As ListItem = ATime.Items.FindByValue(Request.Form("9AM-5PM"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you meant having ID as the attribute of your list items, then of course, you can do it. You need to utilise the `Attributes` collection of `ListItem` Here is how.

```
int idx = 0;
foreach(ListItem item in ddl.Items)
{
   // if you'd like the id populated with the text value
   item.Attributes.Add("id", item.Text);
   // if you'd like the id populated with the index value
   //item.Attributes.Add("id", idx.ToString()); 
   idx++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add element `Id` using list item option `Attributes`. Rendered HTML elements will which ever id you pass in.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem("Item 1");
        listItem.Attributes.Add("id", "ListItem-1");
        ATime.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
```